# Derived properties in interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface that encapsulates a time interval:

```
export interface TimeBased {

  start_time: Date;
  end_time: Date;
  duration_in_hours: number;
}
```

I'm using a class to implement this interface:

```
class ShiftingTaskDetails implements TypeBased, TimeBased {

  type: ShiftingTaskType;
  start_time: Date;
  end_time: Date;
  duration_in_hours: number;

  constructor(type: ShiftingTaskType, start_time: Date, end_time: Date, duration_in_hours: number) {
    this.type              = type;
    this.start_time        = start_time;
    this.end_time          = end_time;
    this.duration_in_hours = Math.abs(end_time.getTime() - start_time.getTime()) / 36e5;
  }
}
```

The problem is that had to repeat code calculating `duration_in_hours` every time I'm implementing the interface. Is there any way I can put a derived field (in this case `duration_in_hours`) in the interface definition itself?

What is the accepted pattern in the TS community? The abstract pattern to convert an interface into a class doesn't work here. This is because I have several such small interfaces with each having its own requirement of derived fields.

```
export interface CountBased {
  count: number
}

export interface CountAndPricingBased extends CountBased {

  unit_price: number;
  count: number;
  total_price: number; // total_price should just be unit_price * count 
}
```

I would want to extend two interfaces which have such derived fields. The problem is that I can't extend two abstract classes.

Comment: That seems more like a job for an abstract class than an interface, then you can just write a `get` accessor for `duration_in_hours`.

Comment: The short answer is no, then; you cannot have implementation in interfaces. You could use `readonly` as a convention to mark properties that are derived, but you have to repeat that implementation if you cannot inherit it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you want to not use an `Interface` since you need logic for calculating the field. Instead define `TimeBased` as an abstract class and do that in the constructor. The deriving class calls it with `super` in the ctor.

Comment: You don't need to calculate it in the constructor, indeed you *shouldn't*, as that would risk it going out-of-sync with the properties it's derived from.

Comment: Then what's the alternative ? Can we have virtual/derived fields ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put *implementation* in the parent, rather than just describe its shape, you should make it an [abstract class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes):

> Unlike an interface, an abstract class may contain implementation
>   details for its members.

As the `duration_in_hours` is a value derived from other properties, it should be an [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors). For example:

```ts
abstract class AbstractTime {
  start_time: Date;
  end_time: Date;

  get duration_in_hours(): number {
    return Math.abs(this.end_time.getTime() - this.start_time.getTime()) / 36e5;
  }
}

class ShiftingTaskDetails extends AbstractTime implements TypeBased {
  constructor(public type: ShiftingTaskType, public start_time: Date, public end_time: Date) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Note this also uses [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) to simplify the constructor.

Comment: Note that, if we use `target: es5` and need to overwrite the `duration_in_hours` in some subclass, we can't call `super.duration_in_hours`. TS will gladly show an error, and in runtime this will crash, due to broken implementation of getters. With `target: es6`, where getters are supported natively, this is not a problem of course.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but then if I have two Interfaces and both of them have atleast one derived field, then I can't extend two classes? This is a real case in my use case. See the edit of the question for additional details.